# How can multiple people concurrently use a single machine with a keyboard and monitor each?

Tags: multiple-monitors, multi-user

Is there a multi-user system in which several users can log in simultaneously?

It should support several end-users with only one keyboard, mouse and monitor *each*. These users should be able to run programs simultaneously, as if they were on separate machines, but in reality they should be running the same machine.

Basically, I need a cost effective solution for computers in a 3rd world country where we could get a single computer behave like multiple computers using monitor and keyboard.

i would also like to have basic idea of its cost.

Comment: I reworded your question, Ahmed Ali, please feel free to edit your question again if I misunderstood it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is unlikely to be satisfactory to your users. It would take a pretty serious desktop to run six or eight users' desktops, even if you installed six or eight video cards and six or eight different USB mouse/keyboards running at the same time.

I think the closest practical solution similar to what you're suggesting would be a [Thin Client](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ThinClients) setup, where each user would have a low-end computer running off your more powerful server via LAN. You might gain a bit in the way of systems administration, but I don't know how much cheaper this would be than chromebooks, and older hardware that could run Lubuntu on it's own might be your best, fastest, and cheapest approach.

Comment: more detail would be apreacated

Comment: More detail on which part? I've tried to set up a thin client just to see if I could do it, and I could, but the performance was no better than the low-end client system had running Lubuntu as a stand-alone system. A better server would have helped, but it also would have increased the cost. Used equipment can be free, and Chromebooks cost $199 in the U.S. I doubt you could set up any type of multi-user system for less per user than that. Also, stand-alone systems stand alone. Outside of your wifi, one problem only shuts down one seat, not all of them.

Comment: thanks mark
the idea here is to setup a at least 5-10 computer running under one computer,
so there could be more computers at school

Comment: I set up the first computer lab at my school in 1988 using old retired equipment so I've been you. The problem with one computer and a lot of terminals like you're thinking is that that one computer better be **very** capable. It will be running 10 desktop sessions with all the overhead that requires, along with the users' jobs. One person renders video and everyone's going to feel it. That one computer needs to drive 10 videos, and the cards to do that aren't cheap. Then there are the 10 user terminals which are cheap, but not free. 10 Chromebooks cost $2000. I don't think you can beat that.

Comment: ok nice answer ,
so i was looking for an optimal way in terms of borth price and value,
in terms of price : i want 4 clients connected to one power full computer so i dont have to buy the vedio cards that are expensive (as mentioned above),
in terms of value : 3 clents x 4  powerfull computers=12 total no  computers, 
and one computer that is 12+1=13 this 13th computer is more powerfull than other 12(4x3 clients) so if there is any overload of work it could be handled by this 13th computer.

Comment: I've purchased thin clients for as little as $20 each.  I've done this, and it works, but you're going to have to do a lot of work.  Mostly the work is getting the clients to read a boot image from your Ubuntu box.  http://www.ebay.com/bhp/hp-thin-client

Answer (score 1):

I just found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration. It looks like Ubuntu and Userful have linux solutions. Full size keyboard, mouse, monitor and 720p video support sound nice for a full desktop experience.

Comment: How is this different from @Rinzwind's comment above?

Comment: While posting a link is helpful it is recommended and advised to also copy the essentials parts to get it running here.

Comment: Good point, I don't usually look at comments on the question!